# Проблемы с css во vue приложении при подключении к gp

Tags: css, vue.js

Всем привет!Сделал приложение на vue.Выкладываю проект на github pages и начинаются проблемы с css,а главный фокус в том , что некоторые стили работают некоторые нет. Опыта работы с вебпак мало и поэтому прошу вас мне помочь ) Ссылка на webpack https://github.com/ronin1991/cats/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: лучше дайте ссылку на github pages

Comment: https://ronin1991.github.io/cats/

Comment: это библиотека vue? это ведь тестовое задание какой-то компании по вебу. Требование именно приложение?

Comment: я решил так реализовать... вот и получилась проблема

Comment: да vue и непонятно почему не все стили вкл